# How can solve this Solver Excel like problem in R?

Tags: r, optimization, intervals

[image]

I have difficulty implement the following optimization problem which I know the solution as presented in excel and now I am trying to implement it in R.

The data are :

```
Kurt=4
Skew =-0.2
```

as k and t respectively as shown in the picture.

Finding the lower and upper omega is simple in R:

For the lower omega:

```
w1 = c(-Kurt-6,0,3,2,1)
f = polyroot(w1)
w11=max(Re(f));w11
[1] 1.206575
```

```
w2 = c(-4-(Skew)^2 ,0,3,1)
g = polyroot(w2);g
w22=max(Re(g));w22
wl = max(w11,w22) ;wl
1] 1.206575
```

For the upper omega:

```
wu = (-1+(2*(Kurt+2))^(0.5))^(0.5)
wu
[1] 1.569746
```

For the upper and lower omega R agrees with Excel.

Now the problem is that the excel Solver finds the omega value to be 1.56425 but I don't know how to verify it in R.

I tried as well the `optimize` function for the upper and lower:

```
m = function(x){ (4+2*( x^2 - ((Kurt +6) /(x^2+2*x+3) )   ))^(0.5) }
om = function(x){(x-1-m(x) )*(x+2+(m(x) /2))^2 - Skew}
optimize(om,interval = c(wl,wu), maximum = TRUE)
```

but I don't know how to to find the result 1.56425 between upper and lower omega as described in the photo.It makes a Solver in Excel but I don't know to perform it in R.

Excuse me for the photo but stack overflow does not have latex in order to present it properly.

Any help ? How can I do it in R?

The excel sheet is this the below picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to give more information/explanations so that people can really replicate your example. (For instance, what is `m`, and why is it a function of `x`? Why do you optimize in the last step, instead of looking for a zero?).

In any case, one way to verify Excel's solution is to plug it into the equation and see if the equation holds.

Also, you can also plot your function in order to see why the optimization might fail:

```
plot(x = seq(wl, wu, length.out = 50),
     y = om(seq(wl, wu, length.out = 50)))
```

*Update*
Thanks for the additional information. (You also want to post the source of the description.) It seems you have at least two coding errors in your functions. Try:

```
m <- function(x){
    (4 + 2*(x^2 - ((Kurt + 6) /(x^2 + 2*x + 3))))^(0.5) - 2
}
om <- function(x){
    (x - 1 - m(x))*(x + 2 + (m(x) /2))^2 - Skew^2
}
uniroot(om, interval = c(wl,wu))
## $root
## [1] 1.56425
## 
## $f.root
## [1] 3.204998e-05
## 
## $iter
## [1] 3
## 
## $init.it
## [1] NA
## 
## $estim.prec
## [1] 6.103516e-05
```

Note that I use `uniroot` because you are looking for a zero (a.k.a. a root).

Comment: I have added a picture in the beginning of the OR that described m.